# Homogeneous fns

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

A function $g$:$\mathbb{R}^3→\mathbb{R}$ is said to be homogeneous of degree $k$ if $g(tx,ty,tz)=t^kg(x,y,z)$, $t>0$. If $g$ is differentiable and homogeneous of degree $k$, then
$$xg_x+yg_y+zg_z=kg$$

Prove that if the functions $a,b$  and $c$ are homogeneous of degree $k$ and the differential form $$w=adx+bdy+cdz$$ is closed, then $w=df$, where $$f=\frac{xa+yb+zc}{k+1}$$

My first approach is differentiate $f$ by $x,y,z$ respectively. $f_x=\frac{a}{k+1},f_y=\frac{b}{k+1},f_z=\frac{c}{k+1}$. I'm not sure about this but I guess, I can write $w=\frac{a}{k+1}dx+\frac{b}{k+1}dy+\frac{c}{k+1}dz$ since $w=df$.

Then replacing $g$ to $f$; $xf_x+yf_y+zf_z=x\frac{a}{k+1}+y\frac{b}{k+1}+z\frac{c}{k+1}=kf$.  //(Edit1: It only equals to $f$ I guess.)

Does my attempt okay to prove $a,b$ and $c$ are homogeneous? Thanks!

(Edit2: I don't want to use $dw$ because it equals to $0$. Don't figure out how to implement it.)

Answer (score 1):

Your formulas for partial derivatives of $f$ are wrong. Keep in mind that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are not constant expressions. When differentiating you should take them into account:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
f_x = \frac{1}{k+1}\left( (a + xa_x) + yb_x + zc_x \right) \\
f_y = \frac{1}{k+1}\left( xa_y + (b + yb_y) + zc_y \right) \\
f_z = \frac{1}{k+1}\left( xa_z + yb_z + (c + zc_z) \right) \\
\end{array}
$$
Then, compute $d\omega$:
$$
d\omega = 
(b_x - a_y)\; dx \wedge dy + 
(c_y - b_z)\; dy \wedge dz + 
(a_z - c_x)\; dz \wedge dx
$$
On the other hand $d\omega=0$, so we conclude that
$$
\begin{array}{c}
b_x = a_y \\
c_y = b_z \\
a_z = c_x \\
\end{array}
$$
For $f_x$ we have:
$$
f_x 
= \frac{a + xa_x + yb_x + zc_x}{k+1}
= \frac{a + xa_x + ya_y + za_z}{k+1}.
$$
Then use the fact that $a$ is homogeneous of degree $k$.

Apply similar reasoning to $f_y$ and $f_z$ to prove the demanded identity.